# How do you prevent an instance using a socketio.AsyncClient code from blocking?

Tags: python-asyncio, python-socketio

I am struggling with the following piece of code. Once instantiated, it is intended to be a component of a containing object. In my mind the containing object should be able to instantiate multiple Connectors, all using the same default asyncio loop.

```
class Connector:

    def __init__(self, address):

        self._address = address

        self._asyncClient = socketio.AsyncClient()

        self._asyncClient.on('connect',
                             handler=self.on_connect,
                             namespace='/aNamespace')

        self._asyncClient.on('connect_error',
                             handler=self.on_connect_error,
                             namespace='/aNamespace')

        self._asyncClient.on('disconnect',
                             namespace='/aNamespace',
                             handler=self.on_disconnect)

        t = asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(self.startup_async_client())
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(t)        

    async def startup_async_client(self):
        await self._asyncClient.connect(self._address, namespaces='/aNamespace')
        await self._asyncClient.wait()

    (...other methods omitted...)
```

The problem lies in the last line: `await self._asyncClient.wait()`. Without it, the Connector instance seems to disconnect immediately after connecting and neither the on_connect/on_disconnect methods seems to be triggered (I know that a connection takes place through the server-side log).

On the other hand, if the wait() line is in place the Connector instance behaves as expected, happily chatting with the server - the on_connect/on_disconnect methods, and others, are triggered as expected. But then I'm stuck, because wait() is blocking the thread and I cannot, say, instantiate other connectors after the first.

What can I do differently then? Should I perhaps use a different way to execute the startup_async_client coroutine?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is not that the `wait()` call on the Socket.IO client is mandatory, it is that without the wait you are exiting the loop immediately after connecting.

Your startup method calls the connect method and then waits for the connection to end. If you call `run_until_complete()` on this method everything works great.

But if you remove the `wait()` call, the asyncio loop will exit immediately after connecting, and not in a graceful way. If you want to remove the `wait()`, then you need to have something in your main task that keeps the loop going. That is the only requirement for the Socket.IO client to continue working.